# Item is shifted way too much to the left, no clue how to change the position

Tags: java, swing, jtable

For some odd reason all my column 1 items are moved to the left of my screen, and so I cannot see it unless I add a String with a bunch of spaces, eg. "----- This works" whereas '4' this would not work.

In the table below I added an example if I add a bunch of spaces with a string and then with a normal number.

1. I have tried googling for a solution but for some reason,
   I cannot find any likewise situations.
2. I have tried to mess around with the layout but it only makes everything scrambled.

I added a picture of the result:

[image]

Comment: Post the code, not a picture of the code. Oh, you haven't even posted a picture of the code, but of the UI. How can anyone help you based on that?

Comment: BTW *"Item is shifted way too much to the left, no clue how to change the position?"* a statement does not become a question by adding `?` to the end of it. What is your ***question?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a method that allows you to set your JTable's columns alignment by making changes to the default Table Cell Renderer. Read the comments within code:

```
/**
 * Sets the Table Cells alignment for whichever table column you like. You can 
 * set the alignment for any column of cells providing you know the Header Column 
 * Name. One column of cells or all columns of cells can have the alignment modified. 
 * It's all a matter of how you supply the configuration data within the <b>{@code
 * columnName}</b> parameter (see below).<br><br>
 * 
 * @param theTable (JTable) Here you provide the JTable variable name for which to 
 * work with.<br>
 * 
 * @param columnName (String) <b>Read this section carefully!</b> It's important if 
 * you want success with the use of this method. 
 * 
 * There are three ways to set the alignment of one or more JTable columns and they 
 * are as follows:<pre>
 * 
 *      1) Supply a single Header Column Name in this parameter then set
 *         its' desired cell alignment within the optional alignType par-
 *         ameter, for example:
 * 
 *          alignJTableCells(jTable1, "ID", 4);          // 4 = Right Align 
 *          alignJTableCells(jTable1, "First Name", 2);  // 2 = Left Align
 * 
 *      2) Supply a single Header Column Name and its' desired alignment 
 *         type string delimited with a Semicolon (;), for example:
 * 
 *          alignJTableCells(jTable1, "ID;Right");        // Right Align
 *          alignJTableCells(jTable1, "First Name;Left"); // Left Align
 * 
 *         When setting alignments this way you <i><b>can not</b></i> use the optional
 *         alignType parameter.
 * 
 *      3) Supply multiple Header Column Names and their semicolon delimited
 *         desired alignment type strings each delimited with a Pipe character
 *         (|), for example:
 * 
 *          String alignmentConfig = "ID;Right|First Name;Left|Age;Center"
 *          alignJTableCells(jTable1, alignmentConfig);   // Multiple Align
 * 
 *         When setting alignments this way you <i><b>can not</b></i> use the optional
 *         alignType parameter.</pre>
 * 
 * Header Column Names must be identical and of the same letter case as what 
 * was established within the JTable Header. Alignment Type strings of LEFT, 
 * RIGHT, CENTER, LEADING, TRAILING can be of any letter case (case insensitive). 
 *          
 * 
 * @param alignType (Optional - Integer) Only to be used if the columnName parameter 
 * contains a "single" Header Column Name only. The different Alignment Types with their 
 * respective integer values are:<pre>
 * 
 *      Left        2
 *      Right       4
 *      Center      0
 *      Leading     10
 *      Trailing    11</pre>
 */
public void alignJTableCells(JTable theTable, String columnName, int... alignType) {
    final int Align_LEFT = 2;
    final int Align_CENTER = 0;
    final int Align_RIGHT = 4;
    final int Align_LEADING = 10;
    final int Align_TRAILING = 11;
    String cell;
    String cellName;
    int cellAlign = -1;
    int at = 2; //LEFT

    if (alignType.length != 0) {
        at = alignType[0];
    }
    try {
        if (columnName.contains(";")) {
            String[] colParts;
            if (columnName.contains("|")) {
                colParts = columnName.split("\\|");
            }
            else {
                colParts = new String[1];
                colParts[0] = columnName;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < colParts.length; j++) {
                cellName = colParts[j].split(";")[0];
                String cellAlignmentStrg = colParts[j].split(";")[1];
                switch (cellAlignmentStrg.toLowerCase()) {
                    case "left":
                        cellAlign = Align_LEFT;
                        break;
                    case "right":
                        cellAlign = Align_RIGHT;
                        break;
                    case "center":
                        cellAlign = Align_CENTER;
                        break;
                    case "leading":
                        cellAlign = Align_LEADING;
                        break;
                    case "trailing":
                        cellAlign = Align_TRAILING;
                        break;
                }

                DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
                renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(cellAlign);
                theTable.getColumn(cellName).setCellRenderer(renderer);
            }
        }
        else {
            DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
            rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(at);
            theTable.getColumn(columnName).setCellRenderer(rightRenderer);
        }
        theTable.repaint();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```